# GeckoFX new UserAgent each Tab/browser control

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-agent, geckofx

I am programming a program where I have several tabs. On each tab is a GeckoFX. I have tried a lot of things and unfortunately when I open the new tab and a second browser control is created and the user agent is changed, the user agent of the first browser control is changed as well.

Any ideas?

I would like to have one UserAgent per browsercontrol

```vb
           Dim page As New TabPage("Tab" & Tabcontrol_Main.TabPages.Count.ToString)
            Dim sUserAgent As String = "Tab" & Tabcontrol_Main.TabPages.Count.ToString
            Tabcontrol_Main.TabPages.Add(page)
            Dim browser As New GeckoWebBrowser
            browser.Name = "browser" & Tabcontrol_Main.TabPages.Count.ToString - 1


            GeckoPreferences.User.SetCharPref("general.useragent.override", RandomUserAgent(sUserAgent))
            page.Controls.Add(browser)
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting useragent via GeckoPreferences is indeed global to the process.

If you are programmatically navigating for each tab, you could set the user agent in the request headers for each `Navigate` call.

```
Navigate(string url, GeckoLoadFlags loadFlags, string referrer, MimeInputStream postData, MimeInputStream headers)

MimeInputStream headers= MimeInputStream.Create();
string simpleData = "User-Agent=hello";
headers.SetData(simpleData);
```

If you also want the user agent set when further navigation happens in each tab, then I guess, you would have to listen for each navigation and modify each one.

Comment: To complete the informationset, i will write here down, what i've found out:
It has to do with the XPCom driver. To do it somehow else, it has to be initialized multible times. But i dont know if that is possible. The other way wound be to check if Firefoxplugins are loadable and use one of them. An other way would be to create a custom Usercontrol, with an own XPCom initialisation. But- for now, your answer is the easyest  one. A little bit complex to programm- but the easyest. Thank you very much! (Damn my spelling is bad)